# What is the first derivative and nth derivative of the following function $ y = \sqrt {2 +\sqrt {3 + \sqrt{x}}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

What is the first derivative and nth derivative of the following function $ y = \sqrt {2 +\sqrt {3 + \sqrt {x}}}$

I think taking the ln for both sides will remove the first square root only?
Could anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: You can calculate the first derivative straight forward using the rule for $x^k$ and the chain rule. Check with WA. The higher derivatives seem to be a PITA however.

Comment: Just use your standard rules for square roots together with the chain rule. You can even just plug it into wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bsqrt%5B2%2Bsqrt%5B3%2Bsqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%5D,x%5D and press step-by-step solution.

Comment: @Christopher.L  is it for free?

Comment: @mvw what do you mean by check with WA? Do you mean wolframalpha ? and did you mean by PITA beta function?

Comment: WA = Wolfram Alpha PITA = Pain in the behind.

Comment: @MathLover : As it turns out, the step-by-step on the web page need you to sign up, which has a monthly fee. I recommend the app for android/iphone instead. It is pretty cheap (one time cost) and step-by-step solutions are included. I think it is pretty obvious that it is a bad habit to rely on apps to just DO the work for you, if you want to learn. However, if, for simple questions like this, they can provide you with nearly the same help as someone here just writing out the steps, then why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt x}}$. Step by step we get:

\begin{align}
y^2-2&=\sqrt{3+\sqrt x}\\
y^4-4y^2+1&=\sqrt x\\
(y^4-4y^2+1)^2&=x
\end{align}

Define $f(x) = (x^4-4x^2+1)^2$. By the above, we have $f(y) = x$ and thus $$f'(y)y' = 1 \implies y' = \frac 1{f'(y)}$$

This gives the same formula as in answer by TheDeadLegend.

You can continue to differentiate to get $$f''(y)(y')^2+f'(y)y'' = 0\\
f'''(y)(y')^3+3f''(y)y'y''+f'(y)y'''=0$$
etc. In this way you can find $n$-th derivative recursively. Note that $f$ is a polynomial so its derivatives will vanish eventually (not fast enough to do by hand, in my opinion, but oh well).

Also, you could use [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) for higher derivatives of function composition:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(y)=\sum_{k=1}^nf^{(k)}(y)B_{n,k}(y',y'',\ldots,y^{(n-k+1)})$$ where $B_{n,k}$ are [Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

Since, $f$ is (left) inverse of $y$, you might also want to take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475840/a-formula-for-n-derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-function#475868) and [here](http://octopus.library.cmu.edu/Collections/traub62/box00027/fld00011/bdl0001/doc0001/doc_27b11f1b1.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

First of all. Use chain rule. I'd recommend learning something new instead of relying on app.(personal opinion)

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}}}.\frac{d\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}}}.\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}}\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}}}.\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: +1 because of your recommendation (I very strangly support it).

Comment: What about the nth derivative?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend your answer is good. Your recommendation is really good. But... what about the $n^{th}$ derivative.

Comment: I highly agree with your recommendation as well. I never intended for anyone to simply rely on an app to DO the calculations for you, per se. However, as I pointed out, you can see a pretty good step-by-step solution (much like your own above) to simple questions like this on Wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach (same answer) ...

$y^2 = 2+ \sqrt{3+\sqrt{x}}$

$\Rightarrow y^2-2=\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{x}}$

$\Rightarrow y^4-4y^2+4=3+\sqrt{x}$

$\Rightarrow 4y^3\frac{dy}{dx} - 8y\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{8y(y^2-2)\sqrt{x}}$